# Multiple conditions in guard statement in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way to include multiple conditions in a guard statement of Swift?

For example, if I want to check two optional values are nil using a guard, how should I do it using single guard statement?

Comment: separated with comma

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Check this code

```
func demo(){

    var str = [String: String]()

    str["status"] = "blue"
    str["asd"] = nil

    guard let var2 = str["asd"], let var1 = str["status"]
    else
    {
        print("asdsfddffgdfgdfga")
        return
    }
    print("asdasdasd")
}
```

Guard will check one by one condition. If the first is true then it will check the next. Otherwise, it will execute the *else* part.

Comment: Can you explain why this renders "asdsfddffgdfgdfga" in case str["asd"] is not nil?

Comment: This is more like a "AND" condition since comma is used. Just curious - Is there a solution for "OR" condition?

Comment: I think making a solution for OR defeats the purpose of `guard` statement

Comment: In the above example, you could model the "or" solution by writing `guard let var = str["asd"] ?? str["status"]`. But in general, if the types are different, you can't model an "or" condition in a guard.

Comment: What do you mean by *"check one by one condition"*? Check the conditions one by one? Or something else?

Comment: Well done, got you up to that 100 upvotes milestone

Comment: It'd be useful to print more descriptive strings, e.g. "conditions failed" and "conditions passed" or similar. Just mashing the keyboard gives values that look similar, don't mean anything, and aren't as easy to discuss as they could be.

Answer (score 13):

To answer Prabhav's question, yes, you are correct, each condition in a *guard* statement must be true in order to proceed (i.e., not go into the else block).  In this sense, it is indeed like separating conditions with AND logic.

You **can** implement OR logic, not by using commas, but by using a Boolean condition:

```
guard
    true || false    // this guard statement evaluates to true
else
    {
    print("no, not all values in the guard were true")
    return
    }

print("yes, all of the values in the guard were true")  // this is printed
```

or a combination of OR and AND logic, by using a combination of Boolean conditions and optional bindings:

```
let testString: String? = nil

guard
    true || false,
    let x = testString,    // this guard statement evaluates to false
    true
else
    {
    print("no, not all values in the guard were true")  // this is printed
    return
    }

print("yes, all of the values in the guard were true")
```

This summary from Apple, written about optional bindings in *if* statements is equally applicable to *guard* statements:

> You can include as many optional bindings and Boolean conditions in a
>   single if statement as you need to, separated by commas. If any of the
>   values in the optional bindings are nil or any Boolean condition
>   evaluates to false, the whole if statement’s condition is considered
>   to be false. The following if statements are equivalent:

```
if let firstNumber = Int("4"), let secondNumber = Int("42"),
    firstNumber < secondNumber && secondNumber < 100
    {
    print("\(firstNumber) < \(secondNumber) < 100")
    } // Prints "4 < 42 < 100"

if let firstNumber = Int("4")
    {
    if let secondNumber = Int("42")
        {
        if firstNumber < secondNumber && secondNumber < 100
            {
            print("\(firstNumber) < \(secondNumber) < 100")
            }
        }
    } // Prints "4 < 42 < 100"
```